# how to validate two field and compare if the both are same valued ,one take IP and the other can take IP and URL

Tags: vue.js

I have two textboxes,one can take IP only and the other one can take both URL or IP,if the both inputs are IP they should be the same,what i have done so far,I have a class named it ValidityCheck:

```
          export class ValidityCheck {
            static validationInput(ipAddress) {
           const ipPattern = /^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0- 
           9][0-9]?)\.){3}    )$/;
            return ipPattern.test(ipAddress);
          }

          static validateUrl(url) {
            const ipRegex = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0- 
           9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
            // Regular expression to validate URL without http, https, or www
            const urlRegex = /^(?!http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.)[^\s\/$.?#].[^\s]*$/;
            if (ipRegex.test(url)) {
              return 'IP';
            } else if (urlRegex.test(url)) {
              return 'URL';
            }
            return 'Invalid';
          }
        }`
```

and in my component I have:

```
   ` <TextBox  v-model="url" @input="validateUrl"/>`
   ` <TextBox  v-model="ipAddress" @input="validateIpAddress" />`
```

and in my methods i have :

```
  ` methods: {
   validateIpAddress() {
   this.isValid = ValidityCheck.validationInput(this.ipAddress);
   this.showMessage = true;
   },
   validateUrl() {
    this.isUrlValid = ValidityCheck.validateUrl(this.url);
    this.showMessageUrl = true;
    },`
```

what i cant achieve is how can i find if the Textbox which can take IP/URL has entered IP and then compare to the second textbox which is IP only